# Apache2 WebSockets reverse proxy on same URL

Tags: apache, websocket, reverse-proxy

How to configure Apache2 to proxy WebSocket connection (BrowserSync for example), if it's made on the same URL, with only difference being header "Upgrade: websocket" and URL schema ws://?

For example:

```
HTTP request:
GET http://example.com/browser-sync/socket.io/?... HTTP/1.1
...

WebSocket request:
GET ws://example.com/browser-sync/socket.io/?... HTTP/1.1
Connection: upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
...
```

All examples I find, redirect some path only, like "<Location /ws>..." or "ProxyPass /ws/ ws://example.com/"

My current config:

```
ProxyRequests off
<Location />
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse /
</Location>
```

mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http and mod_proxy_wstunnel are enabled.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Answering myself.

Using RewriteEngine, hint given by [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/623027/283030), and WebSocket handshake specification:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]

ProxyRequests off
<Location />
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse /
</Location>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, was looking for this and will definitely try this one.

Comment: Helped me a lot - didn't think turning ProxyRequests to off would do the trick, but that ended up being the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Thanks a lot to metalim! I publish the full configuration here for reference:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName example.org
    ServerAlias *.example.org
    ServerAdmin sysadmin@example.org
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://192.168.1.1/$1  [P,L]

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.1/ retry=1
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.1/

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example.org.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example.org.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Apache httpd 2.4.47, this can be used:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/ upgrade=websocket
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#protoupgrade