# How to proxy WSS to WS with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https, websocket

I'm trying to connect to a websocket server that is not WSS over HTTPS. For that, I'm trying to proxy the WSS to WS using apache config.

I've tried using ProxyPass but I only have access to the .htaccess file. So I've also tried using mod_rewrite with a [P] flag, but still no luck.

this is what my .htaccess file looks like right now :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$
RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:9002/ [P]
```

However it doesn't seem to proxy because I still get a connection error from a wss connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RewriteCond` matches `Upgrade: WebSocket` case-sensitively, but (for example) Chrome sends `Upgrade: websocket`. Try using [case-insensitive rules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:9002/$1  [P,L]
```

See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29823699/200445